# Capture screen from a Silverlight Application to be included in a printed report

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, screenshot

I want to include in a report (e.g., written in a word file) a screen shot from a Silverlight application. The problem is that the image resolution is very bad and the printed result is unsatisfactory when using the print-screen button.

Is there a way to create better screen captures?

Note: I have access to the source code and i can modify the application if needed. The app is written in Silverlight version 4.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sample code I use to capture a UIElement and save it as a .png image. The resolution is the size of the displayed element at the time you capture it.

I use PngEncoder from the [ImageTools](http://imagetools.codeplex.com) library. You need to add references to it in your project.

Here's a simple XAML page displaying a blue square with green borders, and a button to capture it:

```
<UserControl x:Class="SilverlightApplication1.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <StackPanel>
            <Border x:Name="myElement"
                    Width="200"
                    Height="200"
                    BorderBrush="Green"
                    Background="AliceBlue"
                    BorderThickness="2" />
            <Button Click="SaveScreenShot"
                    Content="Capture"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

And here's the SaveScreenShot method:

```
private void SaveScreenShot(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //Capture the element
    var screenShot = new WriteableBitmap((UIElement)myElement, null);

    var encoder = new PngEncoder();

    SaveFileDialog saveDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
    saveDialog.Filter = "Picture Files (*.png)|*.png";

    bool? result = saveDialog.ShowDialog();
    if (result.Value)
    {
        using (Stream saveStream = saveDialog.OpenFile())
        {
            encoder.Encode(screenShot.ToImage(), saveStream);
        }
    }
}
```

When clicking the button, it will open a dialog for you to save the captured image as a file. You cannot use the clipboard as Silverlight doesn't allow to put images in it (See the "remarks" section of the [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.clipboard%28VS.95%29.aspx))

So if you add the button with the associated method in your page, and change the "myElement" in the callback to the name of the element you want to capture, you should be good.

Comment: Hi i don't have a code written for capturing, i just mentioned it in case someone posted a code for doing this. Unfortunately i cannot run your code, there must be a problem with silverlight and the library as a blank page appears after compilation. Would this method save the image at a good resolution suitable for printing?

Comment: Ok, I misread the question, I thought you already has some code. I've edited the answer accordingly.
In the code I've provided, you need to replace "myElement" with the root visual element of what you're trying to capture.